# Exchange 2007 - shell command to delete content and folders

Tags: exchange-2007

I have a user that has 450 folders under a root folder called Active. Is there shell command to not only delete the contents of the folders, but the folders themselves?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowlegde goes, you cannot delete a mailbox subfolder in a specific mailbox from the shell, you can however:

Give yourself FullAccess permissions on the mailbox in question:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "TheOtherUser" -AccessRights FullAccess -User "YourUsername"
```

Then add the mailbox in Outlook (Go to accounts -> choose your account -> change -> email -> add), and then delete the folder you wish to remove